# Cannot store input field in JS variable

Tags: javascript

I want to store access to the input field in a var (not just the value) but I get null.

```
<input id="input-note-title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="New Note Title">
```

And here is the Javascript.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('#input-note-title');
console.log(foo);
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/KungFuPandemonium/pen/rLwOGK?editors=1111)

Comment: Thanks. @xufox Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Someone posted it before and it was received well. I will let this stay for future google landings because my question title is more keyword friendly and people would benefit from it with the price of me looking like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foo = document.getElementById('input-note-title').value;
console.log(foo);
```

That should work. Removing the # and getting the value of the element should work. Now you are calling that also before any result so you should probably add a button or something and only call that JS code on change on when someone clicks a button. Because currently it will get the value on page load when there is no value.

EDIT: My bad. Didn't catch the part about just storing the element. So removing the value should store the entire element. Also no need for button or waiting for action.

Comment: @Xufox my bad... didn't catch that part. So just removing the # should work. Will make an edit now.